# In Skyrim, if Shadowmere (or ally) kills an enemy do I get points?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is Experience handled with Companions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/how-is-experience-handled-with-companions)

Playing Skyrim, I just received the semi-invincible horse, Shadowmere from the Brotherhood of Assassins. He automatically attacks enemies, but does he collect XP for me, or do I need to get the final kill to get the XP? Same for summoning allies lie the familiar or the spectral assassin -- do they collect XP for me?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much the same question -- didn't spot that. Sorry for duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no experience for kills in Skyrim, only for using your various abilities. For instance, if you hit an enemy with a fireball, your Destruction skill will increase slightly.

Shadowmere and other followers can reduce the amount of experience you get because you may be using your abilities less. But no, the killing blow is not any more special than any other blow when it comes to awarding 'experience'; each blow awards experience individually.

Comment: It is worth noting that sometimes the death blow _can_ have a bonus effect. For example the Enchanting perk, Soul Squeezer reads  "Death blows to creatures, but not people, trap 5% of the victim's soul, recharging the weapon."